# Making a tall texture more realistic with colours affected by light-direction ond visitors' position?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, texture

I created a tall grey building texture for a wall from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRqmk.jpg). Now if you look at the general trend in the black-white picture, you can see that certain patterns are too repeating. For an arbitrary-sized building I don't know how to create realistic textures: convex correction for light and user position? I used Photoshop to create this texture but some 3D program may be to better here. It should output the light-processed textures. Can I do the light-manipulation with Photoshop or some other tool and how?

[image]

Comment: You aren't being very descriptive about how this texture is going to be used and because of that I'm very confused about what needs to be done. ...involving 3d programs to the process the way that you have, just seems odd. Poorly repeating texture is not going to repeat any better if you add some lighting to it.

Comment: Some terms you can use to help make this happen: "height map"; "bump map"; "light-map"; "parallax map". Mathematica appears to support heightmaps

Comment: @horatio that is very clever, I tried interpolation methods such as [Gouraud shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) but your suggestions excellent +1. Also a puzzle I am trying to solve is to convolve along the connecting line between ends to make it look more fit, novel binarize/level-determination/convolving errorsome so there may be some state of art solution from comp graphics...

Answer (score 2):

You can use mathematical modelling software such as Mathematica and then use *3D parametric plot*. By this you can check things such as texture matching and light coming from different perspectives. The Neutral parameter neutralises the light. You can see here that the texture does not totally match so you need to divert the texture a bit or manually change the texture. Also it is possible that you start a new texture with different transparency until some recursion limit. Then you could get a spiralling brick wall to hide the meeting points of the texture.

[image]

and depending on how you use the texture, you can see for example here how it looks rotated 90 degrees

[image]

and here how it goes over a bended surface. It is easier to see here how the light acts over different angles. I think it looks fine but only the end-start points need to be matched to repeat the pattern.

[image]